# Python absolute imports on OSX

Tags: python, macos, import

Which of the following Python 2.7 import scenarios are correct? i.e. if I have a module with a name shadowing a stdlib module should `import <module>` import the stdlib or the local version?

On Linux

```
$ ls
__init__.py  time.py

~/tmp $ cat time.py 
def a():
  print(¨a¨)

~/tmp $ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> dir(time)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'accept2dyear', 'altzone', 'asctime',     'clock', 'ctime', 'daylight', 'gmtime', 'localtime', 'mktime', 'sleep', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'struct_time', 'time', 'timezone', 'tzname', 'tzset']
```

and on OSX

```
sdk$ ls
__init__.py time.py     time.pyc

$ cat time.py
def a():
  print("a")

$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr  9 2014, 11:48:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> dir(time)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a']
```

PS: Windows seems to follow Linux and using from `__future__ import absolute_import` has no effect

Comment: Are you sure both OSs have your module included in the python path?

Comment: Didn't you cd to `~/tmp` in the first example? Is there an `__init__.py` there?

Comment: why are you using a module with the same name?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think the point of the question is, which of the two namesake modules will/should be picked up. Unfortunately the issue is confused by seemingly running `ls` and `python` in different directories.

Comment: Missed a bit in the copy and paste. Both the `ls` and `python` are run from the same directory `tmp` otherwise the `cat` would not have worked.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. I'm using a module named `time.py` because that's what makes sense (I'm creating a set of Tk entry views and dialogs for date, time and color and importing `tks.time` seems appropriate and should be able to be used). Plus it works on Windows as that's where I'm developing it and from the above on Linux it probably works there.

Comment: so naming it `time` is essential?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's not essential, I've not released anything yet. However I can't see why OSX appears to work differently from Windows and Linux.

Comment: I imagine your mac path has something to do with it, I would recommend not shadowing built in module names. If it is not essential, all you are doing is creating potential problems.

Comment: You're right it could well be a path issue. I've just run some test code in eclipse with pydev and running the code exhibits similar behaviour (importing the local module) but debugging the code imports the global module from the stdlib. I'm not going to change the name just yet but will investigate the pydev scenario a bit more unless someone posts an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Your current path will usually be appended in the first position of the list `sys.path`. That means you'll always import your custom module.

If you don't want that, then you could try starting the interpreter in `python -E` mode. That doesn't add the current path the `sys.path` and you'll have your default module being loaded.

Another way to import the global module is to do a little hack

```
import os

temp_path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/some/other/path')

import myshadowingmodule
os.chdir(temp_path)
```

This makes it seem you're in a different directory when importing, and after importing, brings you back to where you were

Also there's 2 functions `__import__` and `importlib.import_module` - in case you were wondering, you can't use them to import the shadowed module.